# Why does the Symfony URL generator in PHPUnit point to localhost?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, symfony

I am using Symfony 3 with PHP 5.6 and I have setup a unit test with PHPUnit which makes an request to a controller:

```
$this->client->request('GET', '/api');
```

The controller at URL `/api` makes several Curl requests concurrently to the local web server. With something like:

```
do_http_requests([
    $this->get('router')->generate(
        'route', $params, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE
    ),
    ...
]);
```

This fails because the generated URL points to `localhost` (`http://localhost/...`) instead of `web` (`http://web/...`), which is the hostname I've setup for the local webserver. I get an error saying `Connection refused`, because nothing is listening on host `localhost`. The server runs on host `web`.

I have also set an environment variable:

```
SYMFONY__ROUTER__REQUEST_CONTEXT__HOST=web
```

**I would have expected the `router` service to pick up on that environment variable and accordingly generate the URL, as described in [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html). But it does not.**

**What did I misunderstand or miss?**

I would appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have been using this in my tests:

```
$this->client->request('GET', '/api', [], [], ['HTTP_Host' => 'web']
```